# Angular 2 component use css from another component

Tags: css, angular, typescript, components

I got 2 Angular components with 2 different `StyleUrls` for 2 different css files.

ex.
First Component:

```
  @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
     })
```

Second Component:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'my-main',
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
      templateUrl: './main.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './main.component.css' ]
      })
```

If i run my app, the component which I select for second use the ccs of the component which i selected for first.

Comment: Do you want to use the CSS of a different component in another component? If so, add it to the `styleUrls` array.

Comment: no no no, i want that every component use his css file

Comment: I have a tough time understanding what you want but you are free to do `styleUrls: [/* path to any css file*/]`.

Comment: sorry, but i do this, like in my example, and it seems like that it lose this path

Comment: No one can use that code and see what you are talking about. Please create an [mcve] for your question. You can also provide a link to an [mcve] using https://stackblitz.com but do include the code in your question as well.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that you are using `ViewEncapsulation.None` in your first component. Remember that if you iuse ViewEncapsulation.None,  you add the .css of the component as `<style>..your css</style>` in your index.html

Comment: yes @Eliseo i'm using 'ViewEncapsulation.None', i have to add '<style>..your css</style>' to my html files?

Comment: NO, I say that if use ViewEncapsulation.None, **Angular** add the styles in your .html. You need, define yours class some like `.component1 head{color:'red'}` and `.component2 head{color:'green'}` and enclosed the component 1 in `<div class='component1'>...</div>` and equal with the second component. Well the good option is NOT use viewEncapsulation.None, but if you required use, use carafully

Comment: Ok thanks, that is really useful, thanks again